# accessing class name in swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, class

I'm trying to get the class name of a swift 2.3 class as a string like what class.getSimpleName() provides in Android. When trying the following, i get an error, Type Test1 has no member classForCoder

```
public class Test1
    {


        public class Test2
        {
        }

        //class.getSimpleName()
        public static let TAG : String = String(Test1.classForCoder)

    }
```

Comment: You can do it using [Mirror](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror), or `String(describing: Test1.self)`, but what's the problem you're trying to solve here? Maybe there's more swift-y solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 3**

Use `init(describing:)`.

```
static let className = String(describing: YourClass.self)
```

**Swift 2.x**

And in Swift 2.3 it works with `init(_:)`.

```
static let className = String(YourClass.self)
```